# Select folder with ChoiceDialog and return deepest folder name

Tags: files-and-directories

For selecting a folder which contains data files I use the following code:

```
ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[dir], "Directory"], Dynamic[dir]}];
```

`dir` (as string) is the full path name of the folder.

How can I extract the deepest folder name? 
For examples:

```
dir = "F:\\20160111\\data\\folder1";
```

I would like to extract "`folder1`".

Can that be read directly with `ChoiceDialog`? Or do I have to search in the `dir` string?

Example on how I do it:

```
dirLength = StringLength[dir];
start = StringPosition[dir, "\\"];
start = Max[Flatten[start]];
deepestFolder=StringTake[dir, -(dirLength - start)];

Print[deepestFolder]
"folder1"
```

Comment: Take a look at `FileBaseName` and friends.

Comment: Why so easy ;-) thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you.

```
With[{dir = $HomeDirectory},
  Module[{choice, result},
    choice = SystemDialogInput["Directory", dir];
    If[Head[choice] =!= String,
      choice,
      FileNameTake[choice, -1]]]]
```

Two points.

1. `dir` can be set to whatever starting directory you like. No matter where you start you will be able to navigate the whole file system.
2. If you are determined to stick with `ChoiceDialog`, you can still use `FileNameTake` extract the terminal directory in the returned path string.